# How to refresh video.js player for new video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

I'm using video.js as a video player, but I am facing a problem. The problem is that when I'm trying to play any other video, the player does not refresh and it always plays the old video.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import { sendData } from '../../analytics/sendData';

 class Video360Player extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // instantiate Video.js
        const videoJsOptions = {
            autoplay: true,
            controls: true,
            sources: [{
              src: this.props.videoUrl,
              type: 'video/mp4'
            }]
          }
        this.player = videojs(this.videoNode, videoJsOptions,this.props, function onPlayerReady() {
          console.log('onPlayerReady', this)
        });
      }
    
      // destroy player on unmount
      componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.player) {
          this.player.dispose()
        }
      }
    
      // wrap the player in a div with a `data-vjs-player` attribute
      // so videojs won't create additional wrapper in the DOM
      // see https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/3856
      render() {
        return (
          <div> 
            <div data-vjs-player>
              <video ref={ node => this.videoNode = node } className="video-js"></video>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }}
export default Video360Player
```

Comment: Where is other video urls in the code?

Comment: it get passed dynamically

Comment: from here src: this.props.videoUrl,

Comment: How do you try to play other videos?

Comment: i have some thumbnail below videoplayer when i click that thumbnail it should get updated in videoplayer

Answer (score 3):

It happens because your `Video360Player` has `player` and you pass `videoJsOptions`
to that `player` in the `componentDidUpdate` which invoke only once while component is mounted. So to fix that you should add `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.videoUrl !== this.props.videoUrl) {
    this.player.dispose();
    const videoJsOptions = {
      autoplay: true,
      controls: true,
      sources: [
        {
          src: this.props.videoUrl,
          type: "video/mp4",
        },
      ],
    };
    this.player = videojs(
      this.videoNode,
      videoJsOptions,
      this.props,
      function onPlayerReady() {
        console.log("onPlayerReady", this);
      }
    );
  }
}
```